# Custom Jenkins scheduler

Tags: jenkins

We're seeing a problem with Jenkins and the scheduling of builds. Specifically, we trigger Jenkins to build a pipeline of work with every push to every branch of our git repo. On its own, the whole pipeline can take from 10 to 20 minutes to build. This can cause a problem if multiple pushes to a branch happened faster than the builds are completing. Multiplied by the twenty or thirty branches that are in development.

So, I'd like to be able to automatically deprioritise any scheduled builds on Jenkins if they are triggered on a Git commit sha that is no longer the tip of its branch. This is just one example of a factor that might indicate a desired priority. Others would be that branches with open pull requests should have higher priority than those without; or manual input in order to prioritise a PR or branch that needs feedback immediately.

Is there anyway to programmatically interact with the Queue of jobs on Jenkins and reorder it?

There is the [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin), but as far as I know this assigns each build a static priority. I would like to dynamically reprioritise items in the queue based on external info (e.g. from git).

I've found reference to [two](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/External+scheduler+plugin) [other](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/REST+Service+Scheduler+Plugin) plugins whose names indicate that they might do what I want, but I can't find any meaningful documentation on them. The former doesn't provide the options it claims to, and the latter doesn't even exist in the plugins repository. Neither seems to be maintained.

My alternatives seem to be

- write my own implementation of [hudson.model.Queue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Queue.java), which seems like overkill
- maintain a separate queueing service that triggers individual jobs on Jenkins, in which case what is Jenkins even for?

Am I missing something obvious? I can't be the only person who wants more fine-grained control of Jenkins build ordering.

Comment: On our Jenkins instance we have a timer setup under Build Triggers to only check our SCM (svn in our case) every 15 minutes to see if a change has occurred as opposed to triggering on a commit. It might be useful if you can set up a similar timegate so you're still building within a reasonable amount of time after new commits but you're not stacking up a long build queue.

Comment: @Tuffwer, That sounds very much like the "quiet period" functionality built into Jenkins. Adding such a timelag could double or more the amount of time a dev waits for a response from Jenkins, which is the exact opposite of what I want.